# Connecting to a remote server without it's IP and using a relay server

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, port-forwarding, remote-access

I have 3 systems as follows:

Client A: IP not disclosed
Client B: IP not disclosed
Server: some public ip
Client C: IP not disclosed

So, what i'm trying to do is, I want Client C to connect to the server probably via Reverse SSH which has a public ip and simultaneously Client A and B can also connect to the Server to gain access to some ports on Client C's local network let's assume them to be `3000` and `4000` and run commands on client C's machine

### Possible Approaches

This is the approach i thought of:

We can make Client C connect to the server but on a different subdomain `clientc.example.com` and ports are shared as `clientc.example.com:3000` and `clientc.example.com:4000` where Client A and Client B can ssh to gain access to.

There could be an approach with Dynamic port forwarding as well like this:

Client C can ssh to the server with dynamic port forwarding exposing port 1080 to be the SOCKS proxy

```
ssh -D 1080 user@remote_server
```

and Client A and B can have a local SOCKS proxy using

```
ssh -L 9000:localhost:1080 user@remote_server
```

1080 and 9000 are just random ports, they could be any as the user wishes them to be

I could be wrong as well but this just some information i could gather (i have been living on coffee for the past 2 days figuring this out).

Please help me out with which approach i should be using. I think the 1st one will be more resource-intensive and since this is an FOSS project i want it to consume as less resources as it can. the 2nd one will probably use less resources but i am myself confused about how that one will work.

I have looked at some projects like [sshuttle](https://github.com/sshuttle/sshuttle) but they probably don't match my use-case.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'SOCKS proxy' method would work, but not with `-D` – that's for creating a *client-side* proxy, similar to how `-L` works (the 'ssh' client listens on 1080 forwards connections via the server). You need an equivalent of the `-R` mode instead, which should be just `-R 1080` with recent client and server.

Using SOCKS mode seems too complicated; publishing just single ports via `-R localhost:4000` might be enough.

Don't forget that *VPNs* are inherently bidirectional. If A, B, and C connect to the same VPN server, they will already be able to talk to each other directly via IP (using their VPN IP addresses) without any special configuration.

(There even exist 'mesh' VPNs specifically for the purpose of connecting clients with little to no reliance on the central relay.)

Comment: Do you know any projects using mesh VPNs or a mesh VPN server ? That sounds kinda very interesting

Comment: ZeroTier is relatively popular, Tailscale serves a similar purpose, Tinc is old but usable, I've heard of people using Nomad (though it seems a bit too 'enterprise'). They're mostly a performance optimization though – if you're fine with going through a relay server, then you can use traditional WireGuard or OpenVPN or whatever you like.

Comment: ZeroTier seems interesting, Open source as well, But i am just wondering how complex all this could be. I can share my particular use-case which is building VS Code Live Share functionality for Vim i've got code-editing to work with websockets. Just need to make Port forwarding and Terminal access, Is there a easy way? The more i dive into this, the complex it becomes. VS Code Live share probably uses the 1st approach i specified.

Comment: If i use `-R` how can i specify which ports have to be shared?

Comment: `-R` will do reverse SSH Tunneling, How would i do dynamic port forwarding then?